# PHPWord: Replaced image doesn't gets actually replaced

Tags: php, image, phpword

I have a word document (template) which contains some images that I have to replace with others that are present on the drive. The images that exist in the documents are currently blank. And the ones that will replace them have some text written on them. One way to do was to edit each document and then by double-clicking the image I use the Pbrush to edit the image. Other way is below.

I used [PHPWord](https://phpword.codeplex.com/) to do the job. Open the document and replace the image in the `word/media`.

**The problem: At first look it looks like the image has been replaced. Also, if I check through zip/winrar the images are replaced. But when I double click the image in the doc I see the old(blank) image in PBrush. I want the new edited image to show up. Or an alternate way to do the job.**

This function does not exist in the original PHPWord but found it as the quick fix to do the job. `(PhpWord/Template.php)`

```
public function replaceImage($path,$imageName) {
    $this->_objZip->deleteName('word/media/'.$imageName);
    $this->_objZip->addFile($path,'word/media/'.$imageName);
}
```

My Code:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord[$i]->loadTemplate('ALL_FILES/Template.docx');
$document->replaceImage($oldImage, $newImage);
$document->save('ALL_FILES/genForms/updatedDoc.docx');
```

P.S. Hope it is clear what I am trying to say. If need be, I can upload a test document somewhere, in case the problem is not clear.

Comment: If I want to use the function above, what would be $imageName? The id?