# Replace image in bitmap image object without opening document in word 2007 (any language)

Tags: image, bitmap, ms-word

I have a word 2007 document that is being used here as a template. In this template there are some bitmap image objects that are currently blank. The task is to write some text on these images.

The manual way is to edit the document and using paint I write the text on each of these images. But I am looking for a more dynamic way. Anything that can help me achieve my purpose.

I tried to do it using PHP but failed. [PHPWord: Replaced image doesn't gets actually replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425515/phpword-replaced-image-doesnt-gets-actually-replaced)

Answer (score 0):

You can try DocxTemplater, which is a Javascript Library I maintain:

http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html#images

You can do that in the browser, but it works only in modern browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari latest versions). I recommend you to use nodejs.

Github Repository: https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater